# Google Plus button not pulling in image or text (via open graph)

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-plus, google-plus-one

Google has that 'script generator' to create a share button with custom content. Image, Text, Title... but all it generates is the `<meta>` open graph tags that you put in the head. Duh, that's not helpful.

So, I included all that... and the below around the button icon itself for the actual button. All it does is share URL within the string within a-tag. That's it! Any suggestions?

```
<li><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.myveryverycoolwebsite.com" ><img src="images/g_co.jpg" alt="Share on Google Plus"></a></li>
```

If you don't believe me; here is the meta that is indefinitely certainly within the `<head>`

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">

<meta property="og:title" content="Have you seen my baseball?">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:description" content="my website is cooler then yours, sandwiches are good tacos are better yada ya" /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="/images/veryniceimage.jpg"/>
```

Comment: itemscope is [prioritized](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/) over og. Do you also have the required itemprop values?

Comment: Also make sure the page is publically accessible as Google fetches the details with their servers.

Comment: Thanks Lindsey Bro-Haans